# How to remove paddings at the top of PopupMenuItem in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using `PopopMenuButton` instead of `DropdownButton`, but I've run into the following problem. I need to change the `color` of a drop down list in a `PopupMenuItem`. When I set the value, I still have white bars at the top and bottom (attached a screenshot). Blue stripes due to the fact that the `paddings` are set by default. I can remove the sides, but I couldn't remove the top and bottom padding. How can they be removed?

**code**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: widget.width,
      child: PopupMenuButton(
          offset: const Offset(0, 40),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0, vertical: 0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                widget.icon ?? const SizedBox(),
                const SizedBox(width: 8),
                Flexible(
                  child: _selectedTitles.length > 1
                      ? const Text('Selected EV',
                          style: constants.Styles.xSmallLtStdTextStyleWhite)
                      : Text(
                          _selectedTitles.join().toString(),
                          style: constants.Styles.bigBookTextStyleWhite,
                        ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(width: 5),
                SvgPicture.asset(constants.Assets.arrowDropdown),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          itemBuilder: (context) => List.generate(
                widget.items.length,
                (index) => PopupMenuItem(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  value: widget.items[index],
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: constants.Colors.greyDark,
                      border: Border(
                        bottom: BorderSide(
                          color: constants.Colors.white.withOpacity(0.1),
                          width: 1,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: StatefulBuilder(
                      builder: (context, setStateSB) => GFCheckboxListTile(
                        value: _selectedTitles.contains(widget.items[index]),
                        onChanged: (bool? selected) {
                          _onItemSelect(selected!, index);
                          setStateSB(() {});
                        },
                        selected: selected,
                        title: Text(
                          widget.items[index],
                        ),
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 12, bottom: 13),
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 0, left: 0),
                        size: 22,
                        activeBgColor: constants.Colors.greyCheckbox,
                        activeBorderColor: constants.Colors.greyCheckbox,
                        inactiveBgColor: constants.Colors.greyCheckbox,
                        activeIcon:
                            SvgPicture.asset(constants.Assets.checkboxIcon),
                        inactiveBorderColor: constants.Colors.greyXMiddle,
                        type: GFCheckboxType.basic,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: try to add padding attribute in the PopupMenuButton  and make EdgeInsets.zero

Comment: I tried but only removed the indents on the sides